# jQuery split string and add new HTML tags into it?

Tags: jquery, string, split, slice

At Frontend, I'll get the data from one specific database table.
The output is like this:

```
<p class="one">2. April 1507  in Plessis-les-Tours in Frankreich</p>
```

But I need these String into two seperate paragraphs

like this:

```
<p class="one">2. April 1507</p>
<p class="two">in Plessis-les-Tours in Frankreich</p>
```

The split character is everytime the **first** **"in"** at my string, not the second. I'm using jquery 1.11.
At the moment I'm not sure if the SPLIT-comand is the right one?! What will happen if there's only one "in" (word) in my text?

Second example and my code doesn't work:

```
<p class="test">1. April 1647  in Plessis-les-Tours, Frankreich</p>
```

[Here's my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mobilat/xb7Lcm9z/)
It works for that string but not if there's another content.
Can I only split at the first word "in"?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
var myString = $('.one').html();
var index = myString.indexOf("in");  
var first = myString.substr(0, index); // Gets the first part
var second = myString.substr(index); //Gets second part
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xb7Lcm9z/1/)

> I think this is enough for you now you can use these strings as you
>   want

Comment: Glad to listen this. Enjoy scripting.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
<p class="born">1. November 1507 in Tours in Frankreich</p>
```

and the js

```
var myElement = $('p.born');
var myString = myElement.html();

var index = myString.indexOf("in");  
var first = myString.substr(0, index); // Gets the first part
var second = myString.substr(index); //Gets second part 

myElement.html(first);
myElement.after("<p class='bornin'>" + second + "</p>");
```

Thanks a lot!
You're great!

Answer (score -1):

Here is your code which works perfectly as you want.

```
<p class="one">2. April 1507  in Plessis-les-Tours in Frankreich</p>


$(document).ready(function(){
  var myString = $('.one');
  var ary = myString.text().split('in');
  myString.html("<span>"+ary[0]+"</span><br/><br/><span>"+ary[1]+"</span>");    
 });
```

I have updated your js fiddle go through that

http://jsfiddle.net/xb7Lcm9z/3/

Comment: how can it be perfect when it removes all text after 2nd `in`

Comment: Have you checked your fiddle?